# Why does a bad sub-domain go to a search page?

Tags: nameserver

I have the domain windward.net and administer the name server for it on BulkRegister. I have no A or CNAME record for rafiki.windward.net (we used to have this).

So why does http://rafiki.windward.net/ go to a generic BlueHost ad link page?

I'm guessing somehow BlueHost once had this page, but our nameservers are now through BulkRegister and so BlueHost should never see this.

??? - thanks - dave

Comment: `I have no A or CNAME record for rafiki.windward.net` - There actually is a CNAME record for rafiki.windward.net, as verified with nslookup and dnsstuff. The CNAME record is an alias for the root domain windward.net, so this doesn't look like a DNS issue (NX Domain hijacking). It looks like your web hosting company is directing sub-domains of your root domain to a different web page. - https://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#dnsLookup|type=domain&&value=rafiki.windward.net&&recordType=CNAME&&displaytype=pretty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was an entry for *.windward.net in our host records. So anything.windward.net where "anything" was any name not explicitly listed in the host records, resolved to that entry.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no *A* or *CNAME* record for the FQDN you are writing there is not technological reason for that. With my try I got **server not found**. So I agree with the comment that it is not DNS related.

In case you have any answer it can be:

- Defined on some of you local DNS server so the DNS resolver don't request "real world" but resolve it locally. In that case you would have local "outdated" copy of the zone
- You have record on your local hosts file so the local resolver (which is used also by the browser) get know about that even it is not exists in "global" DNS zone. Location of the file to check is:

  - Linux: /etc/hosts
  - Windows: <sys drive>:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Also in the browse once the domain doesn't exists it may fall back to search. In case this is the case the behaviour may be impacted by the selection what you are using as a default search engine...